# How can i set width to a column using exceljs

Tags: node.js, excel, express, exceljs

I am using exceljs to create a xlsx file. I set col width by this statement: worksheet.getColumn("A").width = 3.7, but when i open the real file, the col A width is just 3.
Maybe i miss some things. Any help? Thanks